# Apache2 reverse proxy to Traefik with Docker

Tags: docker-compose, apache2, reverse-proxy, traefik

I've almost got what I want, but there is one thing I can't get working and it's bugging me.

I have Docker running on my server, `example.com` and have setup Traefik to do reverse proxying. I wanted to have as little configuration as possible, so I wanted any container `container` I add to automagically be accessible at `container.services.example.com`.

So I have a `traefik.toml` file:

```
defaultEntryPoints = ["https","http"]

[entryPoints]
  [entryPoints.http]
  address = ":8050"
  [entryPoints.https]
  address = ":8051"
  [entryPoints.https.tls]

[retry]

[docker]
endpoint = "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
domain = "services.example.com"
watch = true
#exposedByDefault = false

[acme]
email = "services@example.com"
storage = "acme.json"
entryPoint = "https"
caServer = "https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory"
onHostRule = true
[acme.httpChallenge]
  entryPoint = "http"
```

and in Apache created a VHost to do the reverse proxying:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ProxyPreserveHost On
 ProxyRequests Off

 ServerName services.example.com
 ServerAlias *.services.example.com

 ProxyPass / http://localhost:8050/
 ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8050/

 ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/services.example.com.error.log
 CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/services.example.com.access.log combined

 <Location />
   Order deny,allow
   Deny from all
   Allow from 10.0.1
 </Location>
 <Location /.well-known/acme-challenge/>
   Order deny, allow
   Allow from all
 </Location>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
 ProxyPreserveHost On
 ProxyRequests Off

 ServerName services.example.com
 ServerAlias *.services.example.com

 ProxyPass / https://localhost:8050/
 ProxyPassReverse / https://localhost:8050/

 ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/services.example.com.error.log
 CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/services.example.com.access.log combined

 <Location />
   Order deny,allow
   Allow from all
 </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

This works well:

- Traefik finds my containers (e.g. `whoami`) and creates HTTP and HTTPS endpoints with route rule `Host:whoami.services.example.com`.
- I can access them through HTTP at `http://whoami.services.example.com`.
- In my `acme.json` I see that SSL certificates are requested from Let's Encrypt for `whoami.services.example.com`.

The only thing that *doesn't* work, is accessing the host through the HTTPS endpoint. When I go to `https://whoami.services.example.com`, I get an `SSL_ERROR_BAD_CERT_DOMAIN`.

I *suspect* that the problem is, that I haven't configured an `SSLCertificateFile` in Apache. I'd like it to serve the proxied one from the Docker container but I don't know how to. Can you help me?

Things I considered:

- Setting up a wildcard certificate for `*.services.example.com`, but my hosting provider doesn't have an API that I can use for the DNS challenge.
- Directly exposing Traefik to the outside world, but I don't want to type a port number in the URL
- Using an alternative rule so that I can access the container at `services.example.com/whoami` but I don't know how to set that up and if all services will continue to work if they're not called at the root of their subdomain.
- Manually creating a vhost for each service, but I want to not have to think about that every time I add or remove a docker.

Answer (score 1):

After some more tinkering I found a solution that works well enough: I just `mod_rewrite` everything to the Traefik HTTPS endpoint, except the ACME challenge which needs to be on port 80.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerName services.example.com
 ServerAlias *.services.example.com

 ProxyRequests Off
 <Location />
   # By default, redirect requests to the Traefik HTTPS endpoint
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteRule (.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}:8051%{REQUEST_URI} [QSA,R=301,L]
 </Location>

 # ACME HTTP challenge only works on port 80 so only proxy that through
 <Location /.well-known/acme-challenge/>
   # Override <Location /> setting:
   RewriteEngine Off

   ProxyPreserveHost On
   ProxyPass http://localhost:8050/.well-known/acme-challenge/
   ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:8050/.well-known/acme-challenge/
 </Location>

</VirtualHost>
```

Now I'll just change the ports (8050, 8051, 8082) to something else and I'm happy (enough).